# how to make 3 combo boxes in java dependent on each other

Tags: java, swing, combobox

for example, I want to make 3 combo boxes
1st one called destination
2nd one called Take off airport
3rd one called Arrival airport
then if user choose destination : France, Take off airport :Cairo international
so i want to make the only available choice of arrival airport is Lyon-Saint-Exupery
also if user choose destination : France, Take off airport : Hurghada international airport
i want to make the only available choice of arrival airport is Orly international airport

Comment: You have the selection listener of the destination `JComboBox` fill the arrival airport `JComboBox`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205642/dynamically-updating-jcombobox-items-when-another-comobobox-changes-indexes/23205712#23205712 for one approach

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, then you want to if you select `France` in a JComboBox Then Other Boxes will show the airports in `France`? or only a single Airport?
Is the answer looking like this? Just Add an `itemlistener` to the first `combobox` and add the items to the other `comboboxes` and make sure to remove all the items from the other two boxes while selecting from the first `combobox`

```
Box1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            if(Box1.getSelectedItem().equals("France")){
                Box2.removeAllItems();
                Box2.addItem("Cairo");
            }
        }
    });
```